# Excel Worksheet Index

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, worksheet

I have the following code that works great but I am trying to modify it so that instead of replacing column 1 of the Index page with a new index I would rather start the range in Cell `C11`. Right now, the new Index starts in Cell `A1` of the Index sheet.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim l As Long

l = 1

    With Me
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
    End With
```

**The above is what I want to have show up in cell C11 and below...**

```
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
        l = l + 1
            With wSheet
                .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
            End With

            Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
    End If
    Next wSheet

End Sub
```

I have successfully modified the code so that the link back to the index on each sheet is in cell `A4` without trouble, but I can't figure out how to have the index be replaced starting at Cell `C11`

Comment: I don't quite follow, but C11 is `.Cells(11, 3)`. Try a little experimenting.

Comment: Voted up to remove rather pedantic downvote. Question is both reasonable and well laid out.

Comment: @AndyG the cell reference was one thing I wasn't certain about - thanks. I've replaced `.Cells(1, 1)` with `.Cells(11, 3)` but still not quite there... will keep working at it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Cells(1, 1)` refers to A1, `Cells(11, 3)` refers to C11.

Comment: @DougGlancy I had to resurrect an old username in order to use one of my better pictures :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this ..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim l As Long

    With Me
        .Columns(3).ClearContents
        .Cells(10, 3) = "INDEX"
        .Cells(10, 3).Name = "Index"
    End With
'The above is what I want to have show up in cell C11 and below...

    l = 10
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
        l = l + 1
            With wSheet
                .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
            End With

            Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 3), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
    End If
    Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: That is great and almost there except now it shows up in column 3 but still in row 2 and onward... and there is no "Index" in the first row.

Comment: @Ben .. this Code display "index" title in C10 .. and sheets link below (I already tested in excel 2007) .. how can it be appeared in row 2 in yours ?